# Grunt bake file include cannot read file

Tags: html, npm, gruntjs

I have the following index.html in my root directory

When I run grunt I get the following error:

```
Verifying property bake.my_target exists in config...OK
Files: index.html -> dist/index.html
Options: content="content.json", section=null, semanticIf=false, basePath="", transforms={}, parsePattern={}, variableParsePattern={}, removeUndefined
Reading content.json...OK
Parsing content.json...OK
Reading index.html...OK
Reading /includes/test.html...ERROR
Warning: Unable to read "/includes/test.html" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.
```

This is my gruntfile.js:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
        src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
        dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    },
    bake: {
      my_target: {
        options: {
          content: "content.json"
        },
        files: {
          "dist/index.html": "index.html"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks( "grunt-bake" );

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'bake']);

};
```

What am I doing wrong. I just followed the docs from this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `grunt-bake` has a bug with include path parsing if baking file is placed at root of folder. Try to put your *index.html* to some folder, like *'src/index.html'* - this worked for me (after few hours wasted).

Source code of `grunt-bake` contains this line so it always put **'/'** to **"include"** file path - I guess this is why it does not work for files at root folder:

```
directory( filePath ) + "/" + includePath
```